# Android studio Using Split method to able to delete the todo list from the data base

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm using the onItemLongClickListener method to create a delete event when long click on the list item. I have the delete task method inside the DAO class. How can I implement it inside the LongClick method?

```
TaskList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int position, final long l) {

            //Get the selected item position
            selectedItem = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            //Create a dialog box to inform the delete
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Delete");
            //Display the seletced item name
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to remove " + selectedItem + "?");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    String[] list = selectedItem.split(":");
                    //Missing something here that I'm not sure

                    if (dao.deleteTask(id)) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Deleted" + task[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

---

```
public boolean deleteTask(int id) {
        //Get a reference to the database
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        //Excute a sql query and get a results in Cursor object "res"
        db.execSQL("Delete from tasks where id = " + id);

        return  true;
    }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

store your id on a separate list e.g.

```
int idList[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
TaskList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int position, final long l) {

        //Create a dialog box to inform the delete
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Delete");
        //Display the seletced item name
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to remove " + selectedItem + "?");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                if (dao.deleteTask(idList[position])) {

                }
            }
        });


        builder.show();

        return true;
    }
});
```